# Which version of Ubuntu is my Linux Mint installation based on?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

For any given version or installation of Linux Mint, how would I find out which version of Ubuntu it is based on? I'm sure it must be in documentation somewhere right?

Comment: Is there a file with *release* in its name in `/etc/`, something like `/etc/*release*`? Maybe there is something useful in it.

Comment: There's a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history) with a handy chart

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You'll find Ubuntu version in the `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release` file:

```
$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
```

To figure out which subrelease you are using, you need to know what kernel you are running, e.g. here kernel 3.19:

```
$ uname -r
3.19.0-32-generic
```

Then you compare it with the [14.04.x Ubuntu Kernel Support schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support) which says that in my case, the **3.19** kernel matches **14.04.3**. Now on wiki it [listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history#Release_history)

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping to find out about something just like this!

Comment: How specific is this information? I am trying to install a driver that says it was designed for `14.04.2 LTS`, but my lsb-release file says I am on `14.04`. There is also a `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION` line that says `"Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"`. Does that mean I have a version just before `14.04.2`, or is it just not specific enough to show the last decimal point version number?

Comment: Answer updated with a method to verify it.

Answer (score 7):

I've done `/etc/os-release`. Here is the result with extended information:

```bsh
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```